# C language: Referencing char arrays in nested struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a 8 byte key with an extra byte for null termination character in KEY.

```
struct KEY { char k[9]; };
```

I have 4 of these keys in KEYS.

```
struct KEYS { struct KEY uk[4]; };
```

I declare these and a pointer to akeys:

```
struct KEY akey;
struct KEYS akeys;
struct KEYS * pkeys = &akeys;
```

I want to zero out all the keys in akeys, using the pointer pkeys.
I tried the following:

```
struct KEY zerokey;
strcpy(zerokey.k, "00000000");
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    pkeys->uk[i] = zerokey;    
    printf("key=%s", pkeys->uk[i]);    //error: crashes program
    }
```

I plan to malloc a blocks of memory for KEYS, but I can't get this simple example to work.

Why is this failing? Is there a better way to do this? Are my structs the best way to do this? I want to add a key, search for a key and zero out a key using the single pointer to the KEYS struct.

Comment: Regarding: `I plan to malloc a blocks of memory for KEYS, but I can't get this simple example to work` - You will not have to malloc blocks of KEYS the way you currently have KEY defined,   i.e. the member char k[9]; has already been assigned 9 bytes for a string.  If you had declared char *k[9];, then you would have an _array_ of pointers, pointing to strings, and would need to allocate pointers for as many arrays of 9 byte strings you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using  `pkeys->uk[i]` this is struct KEY type but you require char * type in printf , instead use `pkeys->uk[i].k`

instead of these lines

```
pkeys->uk[i] = zerokey;    
printf("key=%s", pkeys->uk[i]);
```

use these lines

```
strcpy(pkeys->uk[i].k ,zerokey.k); 
printf("key=%s\n", pkeys->uk[i].k);
```

Try this Modified code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct KEY { char k[9]; };

struct KEYS { struct KEY uk[4]; };

main()
{
int i=0; 
struct KEYS akeys;
struct KEYS * pkeys = &akeys;

struct KEY zerokey;
strcpy(zerokey.k, "00000000");
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   strcpy(pkeys->uk[i].k ,zerokey.k); 
   printf("key=%s\n", pkeys->uk[i].k);   
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

`pkeys->uk[i]` is a `struct KEY`, not a pointer. You are passing the entire struct by value into `printf`, which probably tried to interpret it as a pointer (with bad results).

Try

```
printf("key=%s\n", pkeys->uk[i].k);
```

to pass a pointer to the contained `char` array.